# How to transfer collection of small vector in a unique vector without copy

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a `map<T,vector<double> >`, say `T=char` the values are `vector<double>` of `length<n` say `n=5`. I would like to transfer each `vector<double>` from the map to a big `vector<double>` that will have length `n*mapsize`, each vector inserted at index `5*k`. All this if possible without copying.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef vector<double> Vec;
    typedef map<char, vector<double> >::iterator ItMap;

    //create a map<char,vector<double>> with 2 keys holding resp 2-3 elem vectors
    double v_value[] = {1.1,2.4};
    Vec v(v_value, v_value + sizeof(v_value)/sizeof(double));
    map<char,vector<double> > myMap;
    myMap['A'] = v;
    v.push_back(10);
    myMap['B'] = v;

    //create the vector that should get all the small vectors
    Vec receipt;
    receipt.reserve(10);

    for(ItMap it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
        it->second.resize(5);
        receipt.insert(receipt.end(),it->second.begin(),it->second.end());
    }
}
```

EDIT: I edited with my solution, it does copy though.

Comment: It's not possible without copying; each of the vectors in the map is a separately managed dynamic array and the new vector is a new big array. The values have to be copied. I wouldn't worry about this, unless you have profiled and seen it is a significant issue.

Comment: Maybe you could create some kind of proxy object to use as the map value instead of vector. The proxy would return reference to cells in the big n*k vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, it's not possible without copying; each of the vectors in the map is a separately managed dynamic array and the new vector is a new big array. The values have to be copied. I wouldn't worry about this, unless you have profiled and seen it is a significant issue.

In that spirit, [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to the rescue... de de, de de, dum de dum...

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t length(T (&)[N]) {
   return N;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<double> Vec;
    typedef std::map<char, vector<double> >::iterator ItMap;

    //create a map<char,vector<double>> with 2 keys holding resp 2-3 elem vectors
    double v_value[] = {1.1,2.4};
    Vec v(v_value, v_value + length(v_value));
    std::map<char,vector<double> > myMap;
    myMap['A'] = v;
    v.push_back(10);
    myMap['B'] = v;

    //create the vector that should get all the small vectors
    Vec receipt(10);

    for(ItMap it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
        std::copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), std::back_inserter(receipt));
    }
}
```

For user defined and/or more complex types than `double`, it *may* be more efficient to use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) *if* your target compilers support C++11.

I have demo'd a small trick for calculating the length of an array... I always get confused by `sizeof`.

PS I *hate* `using namespace std`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Unfortunately, that's impossible. This is a good solution if you want to stick to the possible.

Comment: @Alex thanks, I was hoping that `swap` could help. I edited with my answer, but your answer insert at the end, I wanted little vectors to be inserted at the proper place (ie: each 5 index)...

Comment: @statquant I see what you mean, but what do you want the big vector to hold if the original vector was too small? `std::swap` is useless here because of the continuous memory requirement of a `vector`.

Comment: @Alex, 0 would be ok, that's why I resized them in my "solution"

Comment: @statquant In that case your solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

**If** your vector contained anything cheaply moveable and expensive to copy, you could move the contents of each of the small vectors into the big vector using [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move):

```
std::vector<T2> big_vector;
std::map<T1, std::vector<T2>> m = ....;

#include <algorithm> // for this std::move overload
#include <iterator>  // for std::back_inserter

for(auto& e : m) {
  std::move(m.second.begin(), m.second.end(), std::back_inserter(big_vector));
}
```

On the other hand, since you are storing `doubles`, then there isn't much you can do, other than copying. The above would work, but `move` for a double is a copy. So the last loop could be replaced by

```
for(const auto& e : m) {
  std::copy(m.second.begin(), m.second.end(), std::back_inserter(big_vector));
}
```